# How do I make a forward e-mail link?

Tags: html, email

So I want to make a HTML news letter to be sent out. I want to make a "Forward to Friend" button, but how would I link that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Email clients don't provide a way for emails to trigger their Forward functionality.

The closest you could come would be to provide a link to a form which asks people to give you email addresses belonging to third parties to which you could then send email. (If I was that third party, the email would be dropped directly in my spam bin, possibly after filling out the annoying form for reporting spammers that is available from the [OIC](http://www.ico.gov.uk/))

The good news is that email clients have Forward functionality built in, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

The little trick I use is to leave the "mailto" part blank, and then in the the "body" section put in a link that points to an online archive of the html email I just sent them.

Like this:
mailto:?Subject=Subject%20From%20My%20Original%20Email&body=Link%20To%20Online%20Archive%20of%20Original%20Email:%20http://www.bing.com/

In outlook, link is automatically turned into a hyperlink AND their cursor defaults to the "To" field because it's the only thing left blank.

I did this as a quick work around until we code a landing page for them to fill out a form and enter their friends email address, etc.  This way if anyone comes across a link to our archived email on our SITE, they'll have the handy link in it to auto-open their email for them and start a message to their friend(s).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to go with the server side script route.

With PHP, use the mail function and retrieve the TO:$person from a post variable that is sent.

You could link it like:

```
Click <a href="http://bmtk.net/forward.php?**uniqueid**">here</a> to forward this email to a friend!
```

Answer (score 0):

[GraphicMail](http://www.graphicmail.com/gm/home/) do it by adding a link into the footer of the email that takes you to a 'Forward to' webpage (http://www.graphicmail.com/site/forward_to_friend.aspx?SiteID=xxx&SID=x&Section=xxx&FromEmail=your-mail@domain.com&token=&EmailID=X) that allows you to forward the mail assuming that all the newsletters you send out have a unique ID.