# Rails ActionMailer, link_to forward?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

How would I go about making a `link_to` "forward this email" in mailers generated by ActionMailer? I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

The reason I'm asking is because Campaign Monitor seems to make these links (without any functionality) in their templates -- a piece of text implying that this feature can be done -- but I want to actually make these links functional.

This may just be an email/html question in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a forward e-mail link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565554/how-do-i-make-a-forward-e-mail-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the question that Zabba mentioned [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565554/how-do-i-make-a-forward-e-mail-link), it's just not possible to make a forward link. Which leaves me wondering why Campaign Monitor would suggest such a thing is possible....